# Shuffle an array so that no two of the same elements are adjacent

Tags: bash

I have an array which contains strings. Several of those strings can be the same and that is fine. They can be in any order to start of, but most likely they are in alphabetical order.  I have the following `shuffle` function which will shuffle all the elements. However, I want to add a condition that no two of the same string can be adjacent in the array.

For example, this is fine: `ook eek ook monkey ook` but this is not: `ook ook eek ook monkey` as two `ook` are adjacent. It is assumed that the input has been checked so that any duplicates are less than half the total number of elements so a set of non-adjacent solutions exists. For example, `ook ook ook eek` would be rejected. The strings could contains spaces and UTF-8 characters but not new lines -- the strings are actually file name of images.

How can I modify the `shuffle` function to achieve this goal?

Or is there a better way to do that?

```
shuffle() {
    # This function shuffles the elements of an array in-place using the
    # Knuth-Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm. 
    local i tmp size max rand

    # $RANDOM % (i+1) is biased because of the limited range of $RANDOM
    # Compensate by using a range which is a multiple of the array size.
    size=${#array[*]}
    max=$(( 32768 / size * size ))
    for ((i=size-1; i>0; i--)); do
        while (( (rand=$RANDOM) >= max )); do :; done
            rand=$(( rand % (i+1) ))
            tmp=${array[i]} array[i]=${array[rand]} array[rand]=$tmp
    done
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in bash?

Comment: @123 Yes, the rest of the script is in bash.

Comment: @iblamefish Good point. Question edited.

Comment: The simplest (but not in any way random) solution that nevertheless fully complies to the initial task: sort the initial list, split it in two and then rearrange it so that the greater half occupy all odd places (1st, 3rd, 5th, and so forth), whereas even places are filled with the elements from the other half.

Comment: @123 New lines no, spaces yes. Question edited.

Comment: How large is the input? Can you afford a quadratic algorithm?

Comment: @Leon Around a few thousands entries, maybe ten of thousands.

Comment: @Sardathrion, I\`ve finally implemented my idea; see below. Remarks: (1) For simplicity, two strings belong to one equivalence class only if they are strictly equal. (2) The RNG used is not in any way ideal, the whole code is just a proof-of-concept anyway. (3) Additional randomization could be added via randomly sorting last-to-first or first-to-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the rejection pre-condition, it is possible to split the word list into several «equivalence classes» (ECs) — special word groups in each of which words are the same by whatever criterion. Rejection implies that there is no more than one EC that is partly in one half of the list and partly in the other.

We lay a part of this EC aside, so that (1) the remaining part is contained in no more than one of the remaining halves of the list, and (2) the halves are strictly equal in size. Then we shuffle the halves, each one separately. After that, we merge them, the first half occupying odd elements, while evens are for the second half. Then we randomly insert the remaining elements previously laid-aside. It is quite simple, since all of them belong to one EC and thus it is easy to mark places where they can be and where they cannot.

By construction, there can be no two adjacent elements belonging to one EC.

[EDIT:] Finally, the implementation of what`s above.

```
shuffle() {
    local sort="$(sort <<<"$1" | sed "s/^/+/g")"
    local size="$(grep -c ^ <<<"$sort")"
    local take cntr head tail

    if [ "$sort" == "${sort%%$'\n'*}" ]; then
        # single line: nothing to shuffle
        echo "${sort#+}"
        return
    fi
    if [ $[size & 1] == 1 ]; then
        # enforcing equal halves, beginning to extract the middle
        take="$(head -$[size / 2 + 1] <<<"$sort" | tail -1)"
    fi
    cntr="$take"
    size=$[size / 2]
    head="$(head -$size <<<"$sort")"
    tail="$(tail -$size <<<"$sort")"
    while [ "$(head -1 <<<"$tail")" == "$(tail -1 <<<"$head")" ]; do
        # continue extracting the middle, if still left
        if [ -n "$cntr" -a "$cntr" != "$(tail -1 <<<"$head")" ]; then
            break
        else
            cntr="$(tail -1 <<<"$head")"
        fi
        ((--size))
        head="$(head -$size <<<"$head")"
        tail="$(tail -$size <<<"$tail")"
        take="${take:+$take$'\n'}$cntr"$'\n'"$cntr"
    done
    sort=()
    for cntr in $(seq $size); do
        # transforming two line sets into a single interlaced array
        sort[$[cntr * 4 - 3]]="$(head -$cntr <<<"$head" | tail -1)"
        sort[$[cntr * 4 - 1]]="$(head -$cntr <<<"$tail" | tail -1)"
    done
    for cntr in $(seq $[size - 1]); do
        # shuffling each of the interlaced halves by Fisher-Yates
        head="${sort[$[cntr * 4 - 3]]}"
        tail=$[RANDOM % (size - cntr + 1) + cntr]
        sort[$[cntr * 4 - 3]]="${sort[$[tail * 4 - 3]]}"
        sort[$[tail * 4 - 3]]="$head"
        head="${sort[$[cntr * 4 - 1]]}"
        tail=$[RANDOM % (size - cntr + 1) + cntr]
        sort[$[cntr * 4 - 1]]="${sort[$[tail * 4 - 1]]}"
        sort[$[tail * 4 - 1]]="$head"
    done
    if [ -n "$take" ]; then
        # got a remainder; inserting
        tail=($(seq 0 $[size * 2]))
        for cntr in $(seq $[size * 2]); do
            # discarding potential places with remainder in proximity
            if [ "${sort[$[cntr * 2 - 1]]}" \
              == "${take%%$'\n'*}" ]; then
                tail[$[cntr - 1]]=""
                tail[$[cntr]]=""
            fi
        done
        tail=(${tail[@]})
        for cntr in $(seq 0 $[${#tail[@]} - 2]); do
            # shuffling the remaining places, also by Fisher-Yates
            head="${tail[$cntr]}"
            size=$[RANDOM % (${#tail[@]} - cntr) + cntr]
            tail[$cntr]="${tail[$size]}"
            tail[$size]="$head"
        done
        size="$(grep -c ^ <<<"$take")"
        while ((size--)); do
            # finally inserting remainders
            sort[$[${tail[$size]} * 2]]="${take%%$'\n'*}"
        done
    fi
    head=0
    size="${#sort[@]}"
    while ((size)); do
        # printing the overall result
        if [ -n "${sort[$head]}" ]; then
            echo "${sort[$head]#+}"
            ((size--))
        fi
        ((head++))
    done
}

# a very simple test from the original post
shuffle \
"ook
ook
eek
ook
monkey"
```